# How to detect the perfect label position having polygons coordinates for a region in google maps?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have the following polygons coordinates data for Lelystad, Netherlands:

```
5.332127179145246,52.467626991535148 5.331970965072638,52.468478368585529 5.339985197333735,52.471922018564761 5.342336379785317,52.472026121459116 5.340052855673807,52.47186602708171 5.335255658432869,52.469806044919608 5.332037659207283,52.468415901281858 5.332127179145246,52.467626991535148

5.4194037152942,52.509520103500066 5.417731846729617,52.508395181243863 5.394371313350969,52.495109914111367 5.405798471819133,52.502103086672633 5.418249196750788,52.509046647264732 5.418107135676522,52.50974497898337 5.418618341699897,52.509346734432697 5.419599168443415,52.510020373033576 5.425552687134712,52.511094242592073 5.419981074116888,52.509928200797731 5.4194037152942,52.509520103500066

5.423804364580252,52.514285889994397 5.426384223487512,52.513658513379227 5.423104184882624,52.514210845328975 5.421983028853912,52.512540220137637 5.417038352606411,52.511665040794341 5.42201641128192,52.512794682855116 5.425759454051307,52.519714693413107 5.423201032331017,52.514395900130182 5.423804364580252,52.514285889994397
```

and more like this...

When I calculate the center of the polygon, the detected value it's not the best location to place the Region name as Netherlands has a lot of lands "in the water" so center looks weird.
[image]

I'm wondering how on GMaps is decided to place the region labels...

So, does anyone has any idea of how to detect the best coordinates which would describe the region(as on GMaps for example)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that Google calculates the label's position at all.
What do you think about using Google Places Search?
In your case:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Lelystadt&key=API_KEY

You can see the result below:

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [
   {
     "formatted_address" : "Lelystad, Netherlands",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 52.51853699999999,
           "lng" : 5.471422
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 52.6928127,
              "lng" : 5.6059639
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 52.3843956,
              "lng" : 5.2584712
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
     "id" : "95409359bba204dfa8c7fb61548871c897b55230",
     "name" : "Lelystad",
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 534,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112598045772762555469/photos\"\u003eSiebe Swart\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAANs7TjL2gnjoe1qO0QuXeZVFIBs-sv0PW3ZPsrmpomUzAXT87tUsGYV3gYns_eBgwilCiD-IP_FoyQGPm-4Pv-5EgZCoNs6vfnBF_hi3gVL2JFLD-JLdww6wEDDqdGR_1D-aV00oa0qMS6TSHcc-oJNjbso0fns2X8e9JmQBi9k2EhCUP-J5rYmxUS4jjW765w0wGhQCeY0T3YLcN86T9pL7MCUYKb_hgA",
           "width" : 800
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJueLr9pApxkcRtRqmY2hULdM",
     "reference" : "CnRwAAAAeiiAOb9Vx74yWO3LnEO7_bKndCywQ3d45auMCRRrONBCR-ZAfnD3rjCZTyCxMrGsKNbkEUs2zqRmPmiVavV_c8TMf_G0eo4n_jdEHuBCbBoC9QLIpXcbh0qJblGVrMiPCwA5V3GitbS49HLz4cUOyxIQnhNTd-2xnMsL6tFk8cGszhoU3xvtgTVy4X466Vw0liTz-ZgZ3TI",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  }
],
 "status" : "OK"
}
```

I think you can use the `geometry.position` and the `geomerty.viewport` is also different from yours.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Will give it a try, Thanks.